# How to extract Full anchor tag from var in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
```

I want to extract full anchor tag from LinkString.

Comment: Use regex [`<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>`](https://regex101.com/r/xB1sE3/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
    var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
    var output = LinkString.split(/(?=<a)/)[1];
    alert(output);
```

Or

```js
var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
alert(LinkString.match(/(?=<a)[\w\W]+a>/));
```

Or if you are sure that there will always be only one anchor tag in this string then simply

```js
    var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
    var output = LinkString.substring( LinkString.indexOf("<a"),  LinkString.indexOf("</a>")+4);
    alert(output);
```

Comment: @jayeshpatil 2nd and 3rd one should work in that case also. check last one too.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

Split the `LinkString` using javascript **`split()`** function. It return you an array of values seperated by **`:`**.

```
var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
    var output = LinkString.split(':');
    console.log(output[1] + output[2] + output[3]);
```

JSFiddle Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/uxwz3o1k/

=============================== OR ========================================

```
var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
    var output = LinkString.split(/(?=<a)/);
    console.log(output[1]);
```

JSFiddle Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/uxwz3o1k/1

===============================OR=========================================

```
var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
    var indexOpenAnchor = LinkString.indexOf('<a');
     var indexClosingAnchor = LinkString.indexOf('a>');
    console.log(LinkString.substring(indexOpenAnchor,indexClosingAnchor+2));
```

JSFiddle Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/uxwz3o1k/2/