# Extract anchor tag href from string javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I've a requirement where I need to `extract` the `1st href` from a `string`.

Let's say I've a string this way :

```
var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
```

Now I need to `find all the anchor tags` from that `string` and `extract the first anchor tag's href`.

I've followed this sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370474/how-to-extract-full-anchor-tag-from-var-in-javascript) and have tried finding the anchor tag from the string.

But I'm unable to get the first element's href.

```
var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
    var output = LinkString.split(/(?=<a)/)[1];
```

I've also tried `creating a DOM element` from the `output anchor tag` but unable to get the exact href by following the procedure from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/494348/2027813)

My requirement is to get the `Google.com` as a final output.

Can anyone help me getting the href?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a *virtual html element* such as `div` to place the html string value in it then you can target the anchor to extract the href:

```js
var htm="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
var href = $('<div>').append(htm).find('a:first').attr('href');
console.log(href)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create DOM element then extract the `anchor`

```js
var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";
var firstAnchor = $('<div></div>').append(LinkString).find('a:first');
console.log(firstAnchor.prop('outerHTML')); //Get HTML
console.log(firstAnchor.attr('href')); //Get href attribute
console.log(firstAnchor.prop('href')); //Get href property
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have to append it?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, Yes otherwise jQuery will throw error.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qxh8n81/):

```
var LinkString="Google Link Is:<a href='www.Google.com' target='_blank' style='text-dec`oration:none; color:#000000;'>URL</a>";

var dom = jQuery.parseHTML("<div>" + LinkString + "</div>");
console.log(dom);
console.log($(dom).find("[href]").attr("href"));
```

This searches for dom elements that have the href attribute and prints the first href found.